# Trying to learn Fireworks - Driving me nuts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, web-development, user-interface, adobe-fireworks

I have been using Photoshop for the past 3+ years for Web Development until today I stumbled across Adobe Fireworks. After reading online I found that Fireworks seems to be better for the job. So I decided to give it a go. My issue lies in the user interface. Photoshop has a nice sleek interface whereas Fireworks user interface looks ancient, particulary Photoshop Live Mode. If I am going to be spending hours on end in a program I want it to be pleasant. Has someone else atleast created a theme or interface mode for Fireworks or should I just stick with Photoshop?

[image: Fireworks]

[image: Photoshop]

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop Live Effects is a very hacked in way of integrating Photoshop with Fireworks. Perhaps it is best to start with learning Fireworks from the ground up and not trying to closely compare the two programs.

Fireworks excels at mockups. This means it is powerful in Layer organization (by including Pages and States) as well as vector graphic design. It also has a suite of web mock objects, such as form elements. It is best to understand why this is a good choice for web mockups and not as much for graphic design.